# Javascript - read JSON Array without square brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, brackets

So I got this JSON Object. And I would like to iterate throug all the Objects in `nodes` but the Objects the `nodes` Object is not formatet as an Array with `[]`

I can access one after the other, if I know the name for example:

`var X = Trend.L13`

`var node = X.nodes["AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.Frost.AL01"]`

But how do I iterate them?

```
var Trend = {


L13: {
    dataArchive: "datavalues",
    nodes: {
      "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.Frost.AL01": {
        visible: true,
        axis: "left",
        style: "Line",
        color: "#66AF31",
        linewidth: 1,
        nonstop: true,
        stairs: true,
        configname: "L13",
        address: "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.Frost.AL01",
        text: "Frost"
      },
      "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.TempZul.MT01": {
        visible: true,
        axis: "right",
        style: "Line",
        color: "#8701AF",
        linewidth: 1,
        nonstop: true,
        stairs: false,
        configname: "L13",
        address: "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.TempZul.MT01",
        text: "Temp ZUL"
      },
      "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.PuWrg.SS01": {
        visible: true,
        axis: "left",
        style: "Line",
        color: "#000",
        linewidth: 1,
        nonstop: true,
        stairs: true,
        configname: "L13",
        address: "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.PuWrg.SS01",
        text: "PuWRG"
      },
      "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.TempWrgVl.MT01": {
        visible: true,
        axis: "right",
        style: "Line",
        color: "#FF2511",
        linewidth: 1,
        nonstop: false,
        stairs: false,
        configname: "L13",
        address: "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.TempWrgVl.MT01",
        text: "Temp. WRG Vorlauf"
      },
      "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.TempZulNachWRG.MT01": {
        visible: true,
        axis: "right",
        style: "Line",
        color: "#F99602",
        linewidth: 1,
        nonstop: false,
        stairs: false,
        configname: "L13",
        address: "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.TempZulNachWRG.MT01",
        text: "Temp. ZUL nach WRG"
      },
      "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.VtWrg.SS01": {
        visible: true,
        axis: "left",
        style: "Line",
        color: "#A5184A",
        linewidth: 1,
        nonstop: false,
        stairs: true,
        configname: "L13",
        address: "AGENT.OBJECTS.House.SKL04_SK2.L13.VtWrg.SS01",
        text: "VT WRG"
      }
    },
    leftAxis: {
      visible: "1",
      autoScale: "1",
      min: -3.7,
      max: 37,
      description: "Linke Achse"
    },
    rightAxis: {
      visible: "1",
      autoScale: "0",
      min: 0,
      max: 40,
      description: "Rechte Achse"
    },
    time: {
      startTime: 1453010899798,
      endTime: 1453183699799,
      lastTime: "1",
      lastTimeValue: 2,
      lastTimeUnit: "86400"
    },
    newnodes: {}
  }
}
```

Comment: use [for .. in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) e.g. `for (var node in X.nodes)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this piece of code

```
    var Nodes = Trend.L13.nodes;
    for(var key in Nodes) {
      if( Nodes.hasOwnProperty(key) ) {
      console.log(Nodes[key]);
      // Use Nodes[key] in this case to access individual objects
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Here's the fiddle for that https://jsfiddle.net/tp5rd6rL/